# Avoiding the use of a Dagger component that creates unused class instances

Tags: android, dagger-2

If you look at the diagram Google has published on how to architect an Android app:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide

you'll notice that it appears that a single repository is used abstract access to cached data and data accessed over the web. I presume that this repository is a single class and have indeed seen apps built that do have one large repository.

But this raises the question about how Dagger is used when dealing with something like a repository. In my app, I will have classes that will at times need to access cached data from local storage or using Room. Then there are REST api calls that retrieve data.

What bothers me is that if I create a single repository, I really don't want classes instantiated for the cache when the cache is not being used or instantiating classes to handle REST apis when caching is required. In other words, it seems senseless to create a component using Dagger that includes modules for local data access and web access. I want to avoid Dagger from instantiating all these classes at once and having them reside in memory while the app runs. A better solution is to only instantiate the stuff I need when I need it.

How should this be handled in Dagger? Should two separate components be used in the repository or is there some other mechanism that only creates instances of the classes I need when they are required?

Comment: You can handle this with Lazy<T>. It's nice for expensive objects, but it has its drawbacks (mainly memoization). Check https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Lazy.html

Comment: @RicardoCosteira Correct me if I'm wrong, but even if I did use Lazy, once the class is instantiated, it remains instantiated all the time, even when I no longer need it.

Comment: Yes. In that way it is similar to a singleton, but each instance is independent from one another. But if you want the objects to be GCed after, I'm pretty sure you can use Provider<T> (although using it is often considered a code smell, as it might create a confusing architecture with all the different object lifetimes).

Comment: you will have one Repository class but you can have multiple DataSource classes. e.g. LocalDataSource, WebDataSource etc. Repository will use DataSource for abstraction. Now you can inject DataSource based on your requirement.